# Issues in mail received time when using hotmail in php mailer

Tags: php, email

Here is code for sending email from localhost after i referred a lot from online.

html form:

```
<form method="post" action="email.php">
  Email: <input name="email" id="email" type="text" /><br />

  Message:<br />
  <textarea name="message" id="message" rows="15" cols="40"></textarea><br />

  <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

email.php:

```
<?php

// $email and $message are the data that is being
// posted to this page from our html contact form
$email = $_REQUEST['email'] ;
$message = $_REQUEST['message'] ;

require_once('class.phpmailer.php');
require 'PHPMailerAutoload.php';
require 'class.smtp.php';

$mail = new PHPMailer();
$body='hellooooo';
$mail->IsSMTP();

$mail->Host = "ssl://smtp.gmail.com"; // specify main and backup server

$mail->SMTPAuth = true; // turn on SMTP authentication

$mail->Username = "mygmailid@gmail.com"; // SMTP username
$mail->Password = "mypassword"; // SMTP password
$mailer->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';
$mailer->Port = 465;//587;
$mail->AddAddress("bradm@inmotiontesting.com", "Brad Markle");
$mail->SetFrom('xxxxxxxx@gmail.com','Selva Rani');
$mail->WordWrap = 50;

$mail->IsHTML(true);

$mail->Subject = "You have received feedback from your website!";

$mail->MsgHTML($body);

if(!$mail->Send())
{
echo "Message could not be sent. <p>";
echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
exit;
}

echo "Message has been sent";
?>
```

so when i run my code,  i received mail but time is correct in gmail,

If i use hotmail means, the received time is not correct.

May i know know?

Anyone can help me?

Thanks,

**Note:** I m new to php, but i want to know particular this one and fix the problem. and I referred similar questions in stack, but it didn't help me,

Can anybody help me to fix this?

Thanks,

when i check my email acc, it shows like [**this**](http://s23.postimg.org/593oopi9n/untitled.jpg),

so in that image, the time showed., 8.48AM, it is not correct according to indian time, it need to show 2.05PM ..

Comment: The time and date which comes to from server has different timezone as compared to your time and date zone. So change the time zone in your server

Comment: What time you were getting from the output and post your expected time

Comment: You can write in your php code: `date_default_timezone_set("America/Los_Angeles");`. Read the php manual for your desired timezone value.

Comment: now it shows 8.47AM but according to indian time, it need show 2.05PM..

Comment: @Uchiha: may i know, how to add date and time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to my question,

For hotmail time settings,

I modified my hotmail acc, after that it will work,

The steps are,

1. Log into your Hotmail Account
2. Click on Options in the upper right corner of the page
3. Under "Manage Your Account, click on the option "View and edit your personal information"
4. One the Account Summary page, click the link name "Registered information" under your birthdate
5. Select your correct country in the Home Location section
6. Select your correct time zone in the Time Zone section.
7. Click on the Save tab